# Parsing through the path of an URL

Tags: python, parsing, url

I am working with data from tweeter and I am trying to obtain the domain plus the first element in the path after .com. For example, I have an URL :

'https://www.facebook.com/estebanfarfanr/videos/1281699612020348/'

In this case all my dataset has Facebook as the domain. What I need is to have the URL link that contains the domain plus in this case, the user id. Therefore I need to be left with:

https://www.facebook.com/estebanfarfanr/

and get rid of the rest of the URL. I have not found a simple way to do it yet, if anyone has an advice.

Comment: use regular expression to parse the string as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manipulate urls in python, you can use [the `urllib.parse` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse).

```py
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlunsplit

def first_level_url(url: str) -> str:
    """Return the url trimmed after the first path level."""
    split_url = urlsplit(url)
    path_parts = split_url.path.split("/")  # The first level of the path

    # Edit the path, trimming everything after the first level
    # beyond root, eg: /first/second/third/ -> /first/
    new_path = "/".join(path_parts[:2]) + "/"

    new_url = split_url._replace(
       # Replace the original path with our edit
        path=new_path,
        # Remove the query string if it exists -- ?example=query
        query="",
        # Remove the fragment if it exists -- #example:fragment
        fragment="",
    )

    # Put the url back together with changes
    return urlunsplit(new_url)
```

Here's how it works with your example url:

```py
>>> first_level_url(
        "https://www.facebook.com/estebanfarfanr/videos/1281699612020348/"
    )
'https://www.facebook.com/estebanfarfanr/'

>>> first_level_url("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68093654/")
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/'

# It will remove query strings and fragments too
>>> first_level_url(
        "https://github.com/blackrobot/foo/bar/?hello=world#lorem:ipsum"
    )
'https://github.com/blackrobot/'
```

Comment: why do we need to return urlunsplit(new_url) instead of just new_url.  ?

Comment: Just so you now I used it and it worked with the exception of some urls in my list that still output something like this:                            "https://www.facebook.com/1133685943410489/?sfnsn=mo&d=n&vh=e"                              I saw all of them in the list and it seems like all the link that did not get trimmed  s how the same pattern of /? after the id. But overall the function, with my question above , I am just trying to understand the reason why we need to use unsplit to return the object.

Comment: @Wara I've updated the `first_level_url` function to drop query strings (and fragments too). The function uses `urlunsplit(...)` because the value returned by `urlsplit(...)` is a `tuple`, and not a `str`. Try playing with `urlsplit(...)` in the python terminal and you'll understand.